# Flutter: adding a gradient to my progress bar

Tags: flutter

Let me first say I started with flutter last week so I apologise in advance for my lack of knowledge.

I'm using a progress bar in my application:

```
FAProgressBar(
    size: 50,
    currentValue: dailyProgress,
    direction: Axis.vertical,
    verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
    progressColor: Colors.amber,
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
    animatedDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
),
```

In reality it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPubq.jpg

I want it to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNHDo.jpg

How would you recommend me to proceed? It seems impossible to replace the progressColor property with a gradient. Is there another package I can use? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try [Gradient Widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/gradient_widgets) package for Flutter.

It has GradientProgressIndicator which should fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks! But the GradientProgressIndicator documentation is limited. I can't seem to find any other properties than gradient and value. To fit my needs I want to be able to define background color, direction etc.